# Use the List component without the automatic fetch

Tags: react-admin

react admin version :  2.9.5

I would like to use the List component without it automatically making a fetch.

For a special case I would like to fill my redux resource with a "manual" crudGetList in my componentDidMount.

In order to avoid a cache effect: when I first consult my list with a specific id my resource is filled with data and then the List component displays my data.

If I change page then consult the same list with the same resource but with a different id, for a few seconds I will have the first data displayed then after the fecth the redux resource is updated and the good data is displayed

I would like to find a solution to this problem by continuing to use react-admin. Otherwise I'd go by material-ui

[image: Gif exemple]([https://i.ibb.co/KGBVq0T/ezgif-com-video-to-gif.gif]

and here my code, StyledCustumTable is the List and DataGrid compenent from react-admin

```js
 <StyledCustomTable
          actions={<PostBulkActionButtons {...rest} />}
          basePath={`campaigns/${campaignId}/lineItems/${campaignId}`}
          bulkActionButtons={<PostBulkActionButtons postActions {...rest} />}
          id="SLM_productsList"
          pagination={<CustomPagination />}
          resource={LINE_ITEM_PRODUCTS}
          {...rest}
        >
          <FunctionField
            label={translate('line_items_status')}
            render={({ globalState }) => (globalState === 'ok' ? <CheckCircleGreen /> : <HighlightOffRed />)}
          />
          <FunctionField
            label={translate('line_items_image')}
            render={({ imageUrl }) => <img alt="" width="70" src={imageUrl} />}
          />
 </StyledCustomTable>
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: please provide an example, its really hard to understand what you are asking

Comment: I'm not able to understand your question completely. I will rephrase your question based on my understanding. 
You are displaying data in the list. Changing the page and fetching new data from API, but still, you can see the old data for a few seconds before it updates the correct data. 

Your data is stored in store and the behavior is expected. You need to clear the data as soon as you come back to the page again. Then make an api call/update your list. it will resolve your problem.

Comment: It’s that yeah. But with react admin it’s really special. I’ll provide example tomorrow. Thanks